# MVC Get Image Orientation and convert File correct Direction

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, webimage

having problem in getting image orientation with below code. Some picture orientation not correct. How I fix it with webimage and convert this code for webimage

Mycode

```
WebImage img = new WebImage(Image.InputStream);
                            img.Resize(600, 600, false, false);
                            img.Save(path);
```

Like This

```
private const int exifOrientationID = 0x112 //274

public static void ExifRotate(this Image img)
{
    if (!img.PropertyIdList.Contains(exifOrientationID))
        return;

    var prop = img.GetPropertyItem(exifOrientationID);
    int val = BitConverter.ToUInt16(prop.Value, 0);
    var rot = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;

    if (val == 3 || val == 4)
        rot = RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone;
    else if (val == 5 || val == 6)
        rot = RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone;
    else if (val == 7 || val == 8)
        rot = RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone;

    if (val == 2 || val == 4 || val == 5 || val == 7)
        rot |= RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX;

    if (rot != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
        img.RotateFlip(rot);
}
```

Comment: Please provide proper isolated code i.e. it should compile in isolation. Currently your extension method will trow compile time error.

Comment: is there some problem with the existing code? If so please describe your issue specifically instead of merely asking "how to". Then we can try to fix your current code.